# Build data frame from multiple CSVs in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, boxplot

(:

I don't know much about R, but I was required to plot a set of box plots from a data ensamble using it.

I have a set of **.csv** files representing a set of 2D data. They contain the following columns:

> i: the row of the matrix
>
> j: the column of the matrix
>
> VBoot: a property of the matrix

My data is 128 x 128, but the **.csv** just contain indices for non-zero properties.

I have to plot a box plot for each of these files, side by side.

This is my approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

# Set the directory to read the files
setwd("/Users/me/data/CSV/")

operatorProperty <- function(operator, property, degrees, m, n)
{
    p <- list()
    for (degree in degrees)
    {
        file <- paste(c(degree, operator, property, ".csv"), collapse="")
        data <- read.csv(file, header=TRUE, sep=" ", dec=".") 
        # Create an array m * n to fill with the data
        b <- vector(mode="double", length=(m*n))
        # Rebuild the complete data to properly build the box plot
        b[data$i * m + data$j] = sqrt(data$VBoot)
        p <- append(p, list(b))
    }
    p
}
```

So far, I just created a list to insert the data for each ensamble.

Then, I though I should build a `data.frame`:

```
min_degree = 0
max_degree = 45
delta = 5
m = 128
n = 128

degrees <- seq(min_degree, max_degree, delta)
property <- "VBoot"
operator <- "Prewitt"
Sobel <- operatorProperty(operator, property, degrees, m, n)

df <- data.frame(degrees, Sobel)
df2<- melt(data=df,id.vars="degrees")
  
p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=degrees,y=value,colour=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    xlab(expression(theta)) +
    ylab("Bootstrap Variance")
```

However, I can't build the `data.frame`. I don't know how to proceed. An example of the data can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ped312ur604357r/AACQGloHDAy8I2C6HITFzjqza).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the final plot to look like? Do you just want to make a box-plot for the non-zero values in each of the files? Or you want all the zeros to count as well? What do you intend to color based on?

Comment: I'm just trying to get each data, reconstruct it (couting the zero there are not in the .csv) and show a box plot for each of them, side by side, like here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Well, I had to change a few things to get this to work with the sample data. Here's the setup

```
m = 128
n = 128

operatorProperty <- function(operator, property, degrees, m, n)
{
    Map(function(degree) {
        file <- paste(c(degree, operator, property, ".csv"), collapse="")
        data <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, dec=".") 
        # Create an array m * n to fill with the data
        b <- vector(mode="double", length=(m*n))
        # Rebuild the complete data to properly build the box plot
        b[data$i * m + data$j] = sqrt(data[[property]])
        b
    }, degrees)
}


degrees <- c('00','05')
property <- "MSE"
operator <- "Prewitt"
Sobel <- operatorProperty(operator, property, degrees, m, n)
```

With this modified form, `Sobel` is a list with named elements corresponding to the different degrees. We can turn this into a data.frame and plot with

```
df2<- melt(data.frame(Sobel, check.names=F))

p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=variable,y=value,colour=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
    xlab(expression(theta)) +
    ylab("Bootstrap Variance")
```

[image]

which looks very funny because you have so many zeros. All of your non-zero entries are just marked as outliers.

But even if we didn't nicely name the `Sobel` list, It basically was a list with two vectors (once for each degree)

```
list(c(0,0,0,0, ...), c(0,0,0,0,...))
```

if you wanted to merge that with degrees and turn into a data.frame, another choice could have been

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind.data.frame, degrees, Sobel))
```

Comment: Thank you! (: However, I tried create a list of lists and map it to a data.frame. What was incorrect (just to learn what was my mistake)?

Comment: Your line `data.frame(degrees, Sobel)` was wrong. You were mixing row data with column data. `Sobel` was a list of vectors each with length `m*n` and `degrees` was much shorter so it was being recycled.

Comment: Yes. What I was trying to do was to build a table with the degrees as rows IDS and associate the Sobel list (witch is also size 10) as the "content".